# Why is my code adding 93 days to the output?

Tags: c++, function, loops, date, leap-year

I have a c++ assignment that asks to enter one date and second date and find the number of days between the two, including leap years. My code displays the correct values for two dates, however when tested for 1/2/3 to 3/21/12345, it displays 4507994, which is 93 more days than the correct value of 4507901. Why is this happening? I am including cstdlib and iostream

```
using namespace std;

bool isLeapYear (int year)
{
  bool tf;
if (year%4 !=0)
{
    tf = true;
}

else if (year%4 == 0)
{
   if (year%1000 == 0)
   {
        if (year %400 == 0)
        {
            tf = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tf = true;
        }
    }
    tf = false;
}
return tf;
}

int last_day(int month, int year)
{
int lday;
if (month == 2)
{
    if (isLeapYear (year) == false)
    {
        lday = 29;
    }
    else
    {
        lday = 28;
    }
}
else if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month ==  7 || month == 8|| month == 10 || month ==12)
{
    lday = 31;
}
else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
{
    lday = 30;
}
return lday;
}

void howlongwait (int &month, int &day, int &year)
{

if (day == last_day(month, year))
{
    if (month == 12 && day == 31)
    {
        month = 1;
        day = 1;
        year = year+1;
    }
    else
    {
        month = month+1;
        day = 1;
        year = year;
     }
  }
    else
    {
    month = month;
    day = day+1;
    year = year;
    }
}


int main()
{
 int month, month2, day2, day, year, year2;
 int days = 0;
 char trash, garb, garb2, trash2;
 cout << "Enter start date (no spaces): " << endl;
 cin >> month >> trash >> day >> garb >> year;
 cout << "Enter end date (no spaces): " << endl;
 cin >> month2 >> trash2 >> day2 >> garb2 >> year2;
 if (year2 < year)
{
    cout << "Never..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
   while ((month != month2) || (day != day2) || (year != year2))
    {
        howlongwait (month, day, year);
        days=days+1;
    }
}
 cout << "You have to wait " << days << " days" << endl;
}
```

`

Comment: You're missing an `else` in `isLeapYear`...  And (unrelated) your naming is backwards, since "isLeapYear" returns false when it is a leap year.

Comment: One way you can go about this is to narrow your input until you home in on a problem. Halve the number of days and try again. Repeat that with a half that gives an incorrect result until you find an exact date that exhibits the problem. For a starting range of 4.5 million, this only takes around 20 repetitions. Once you have an exact date to watch for, you can examine each line of code as it processes that date and see which line causes it to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`isLeapYear` should be fixed like this:

```cpp
bool isLeapYear (int y)
{
    return y%4 == 0 && (y%400 == 0 || y%100 != 0);
}
```

and please replace `isLeapYear (year) == false` to `isLeapYear (year) == true`.

---

Your version of `isLeapYear` is:

- `year%1000 == 0` should be `year%100 == 0`
- corresponding `else` is missing
- flip `true` and `false`, or change the function name if you need